# How to convert a string to a json structure in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following string:

```
DBUser = XXX;
```

I would like to convert the string to a json format so it would be something like:

```
{"DBUSER" : "XXX"}
```

The solution that I tried is:

```
return "{ " + @"""DBUser""" + ":"+ "\"{x}\"" + "}" ;
```

The result that I get which not matching the json structure is

```
"{ \"DBUser\":\"{x}\"}"
```

Comment: You probably should be using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do this, not mashing strings together.

Comment: okay would that library has a way of converting the string to json structure

Comment: If you ignore the backslashes, does the string `"{ \"DBUser\":\"{x}\"}"` match what you want?  Those backslashes are just there to escape the double quotation marks, so if you're seeing that as the value in your debugger, it's already correct.

Comment: yes I still see the backslashes in the postman but I was thinking that I would be much better to use a library or methods that converts the string to json format

Comment: If you're already starting with strings, then you just type out the *actual* string.  But I doubt you're starting with strings.  You've got a DBUser variable somewhere that's storing your DBUser.  Learn how to use Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: what exactly is this string ? How do you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object.

```
    var user = new User()
    {
      DBUser = "XXX"
    };
```

Then serialize the object.

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; 
    var v = (JObject)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

Comment: Sure, if an actual DBUser variable exists.